# Record the audio stream from HDMI monitor

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording

I am trying to record sound playing on my comupter with Audacity but am running into some troubles.

I have the stereo mix set to be the default audio recorder but it doesn't pick up the audio that is being played through my HDMI monitors speakers:

Playback
[image: Playback]

Recording
[image: Recording]

When I plug in headphones the stereo mix will pick up the audio stream and I can record but not when playing through the HDMI. I have installed the latest audio drivers and have tried all the different record options to no avail.

How can I capture the Audio stream going through the HDMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stereo Mix is a feature of your sound card providing a recording device that mirrors the card's output. If you're using a different playback device than the Realtek, as is the case when using HDMI, there will be no signal on its output and as a result, no signal on the Stereo Mix recording device either.

Your playback device in this scenario is your GPU, which is unlikely to have a similar feature. You'll need to intercept the audio using dedicated software such as a virtual sound card.

Answer (score 0):

A few years have gone by. We can use gstreamer pipelines to record audio and pipe it around.

Record from microphone.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=output.wav
```

Record "what you hear" while sound or video is playing.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e pulsesrc device=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=output.wav
```

Record what you hear while forwarding it to hdmi

```
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc device=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=output.wav ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw, rate=44100, channels=2, format=S16LE ! pulsesink device=hdmi-stereo
```

Devices might be different on your system. To find others.

```
pactl list|grep source
pactl list|grep sink
```